# PrimeNG: Tooltip freezes when option is selected from dropdown

Tags: angular2-forms, primeng

PrimeNG Tooltip get freeze and does not hide automatically when an option is selected from the PrimeNG dropdown. On hover and on click, tooltip is working fine except when an option is selected.

Template code is below:

`<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="equipmentFeature" class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Equipment Feature</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                    <p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" placeholder="--Select--" [options]="equipmentFeatures"
                        name="equipmentFeature" pTooltip="Select Equipment Feature" tooltipPosition="right">
                    </p-dropdown>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing tooltip element from DOM on selected option changed.

Added **onChange** event in HTML template:

```
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="equipmentFeature" class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Equipment Feature</label>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-9">
                <p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'100%'}" filter="true" filterPlaceholder="Search" placeholder="--Select--" [options]="equipmentFeatures"
                    [(ngModel)]="currentRateData.equipmentFeature" name="equipmentFeature" pTooltip="Select Equipment Feature"
                    tooltipPosition="right" (onChange)="onFeatureChange()">
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Added event handler for **onChange** event in Angular Component class:

```
    onFeatureChange()
{
    //it's just a hack for tooltip frozen on dropdown option selected issue.
    let elem = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('.ui-widget.ui-tooltip.ui-tooltip-right');
    elem.remove();
}
```